# Did Gandhi ever make a comment about Islam?

Tags: india, islam, christianity, quotes

Gandhi famously said about Christians:

> I like your Christ, I do not like your Christians. Your Christians are so unlike your Christ.

I realise that in his time the Indian subcontinent was being divided between Hindu regions and Muslim regions, so I would have expected him to have some comment or opinion about Islam or Muslims in general.

Did he ever make a similar comment about Muslims or Islam?

Comment: +1 It fits in history. How come Gandhi, who comment about christianity does not comment about islam, which is a far more influential religion in India.

Comment: @Pureferret Ghandi?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar comment"? Are you expecting he said "I like Mohammed but I don't like Muslims?" That's highly unlikely.

Comment: @Rajib something that shows an opinion, for or against.

Comment: This quote may be wrongly attributed to Gandhi. See [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/did-mahatma-gandhi-say-i-like-your-christ-i-do-not-like-your-christians). In any case I don't think there can be a "for-or-against" opinion on any religion by Gandhi. He was trying to unite all under one umbrella. He would thus have (at least publicly) respected all religions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw this question today, maybe because it was modified recently. Even though this question has an accepted answer, I would like to add some quotes, might be helpful to anyone reading this in future. Feel free to refer to the digitised books available on [gandhiashramsevagram.org](https://www.gandhiashramsevagram.org/)

1. > To those who have been indulging in a campaign of abuse and vilification I
   > would say, 'Islam enjoins you not to revile even an enemy. The Prophet treated
   > even enemies with kindness and tried to win them over by his fairness and
   > generosity 
   > <sub>The 'Quit India' Resolution, My Non-violence</sub>
2. > The Allah of Islam is the same as the God of Christians and the Ishwara of
   > Hindus
   > <sub>Equality of religions, Truth is God</sub>
3. > I do regard Islam to be a religion of peace in the same sense as Christianity,
   > Buddhism and Hinduism are.
   > <sub>Buddhism, Christianity and Islam, Truth is God</sub>
4. > In my view, Islam did not attain its greatness by the power of the sword but entirely through the self- immolation of its fakirs. It is soldier-like to allow oneself to be cut down by a sword, not to use the sword on another.
   > <sub>To Shankarlal on ideas about Satyagraha, Selected Letters of Mahatma Gandhi</sub>

Answer (score 16):

The most all encompassing quote I can find is [this one](http://www.hvk.org/2003/0403/196.html):

> The newspaper report that about a fortnight ago my eldest son Harilal, now nearing fifty years, accepted Islam and that on Friday last 29th May in the midst of a large congregation in the Juma Masjid at Bombay he was permitted to announce his acceptance amid great acclamation and that after his speech was finished, he was besieged by his admirers who vied with one another to shake hands with him. If his acceptance was from the heart and free from any worldly considerations, I should have no quarrel. **For I believe Islam to be as true a religion as my own.**

Comment: If a sentence starts with "if ..." I alsways want to read the "else ..." statement implied. Does the quote continue?

Comment: @mart not to my knowledge.

Comment: @Pureferret Can you add a source to this quote ?

Answer (score 9):

Mahatma Gandhi famously said about Mohammad:

> I wanted to know the best of life of the one who holds today the undisputed sway over the hearts of millions of mankind. I became more than convinced that… it was the rigid simplicity, the utter self effacement of the Prophet… his intense devotion to his friends and followers, his intrepidity, his fearlessness, his absolute trust in God and his own mission.

Reference Young India pp 11-18, 23rd September 1924